# Should I return dataset directly or should i use one_shot iterator instead?

Tags: python, tensorflow, iterator, pipeline, tensorflow-datasets

I am building a data pipeline using Dataset API, but when I train of multiple GPUs and return `dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()` in my input function, I get

```
ValueError: dataset_fn() must return a tf.data.Dataset when using a tf.distribute.Strategy
```

I can follow the error message and return dataset directly, but I do not understand the purpose of `iterator().get_next()` and how it works for training on single vs multiple GPU.

```
...

    dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size = batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.cache()

    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=None)

    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

return _input_fn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `tf.data` with distribution strategy (which can be used with Keras and `tf.Estimator`s), your input fn should return a `tf.data.Dataset`:

```
def input_fn():
  dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size = batch_size)
  dataset = dataset.cache()

  dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=None)
  return dataset

...use input_fn...
```

See [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/README.md) on distribution strategy.

`dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()` is useful outside of distribution strategies / higher level libraries, for example if you are using lower level libraries, or debugging / testing a dataset. For example, you can iterate all a dataset's elements like so:

```
dataset = ...
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
get_next = iterator.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  while True:
    print(sess.run(get_next))
  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    break
```